# Custom permalink structure disturbs my jQuery/AJAX function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am using [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin to set a custom structure for my permalinks using only settings/general in the admin area of Wordpress.

The custom permalink structure I am using is :

```
/%postname%/%product_category%/
```

In addition, I have under my `single-CPT.php` page a select tag that triggers some jquery/ajax actions. When I remove the custom permalink structure, which automatically activates the default permalink strucure,  everything works like a charm. But after activating the above structure, the DIV that should display results resturned by jquery/ajax,embeds the whole page in a weird manner.

My jquery code is:

```
$('select.select').change(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var value = $('select.select option:selected').val(); 

    create_ayat_selectCPT(value); // AJAX function


})
```

Thank you very much for your help, I am 2 days digging to find the solution.

**Note** that I am using cutom post types in my website.

**Edit:**
Taking into consideration Damon answer, the permalink structure affects the behaviour of the jquery/ajax function. In fact, if I change to `/%product_category%/%postname%/`, the Ajax call is executed but with no success.

**Result:** I have actually the alert displaying the error message.

The function jquery/ajax function is :

```
function create_ayat_selectCPT(str) 
{

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'createAyatSelectCPT', id: str}),
                    success: function(data){

                    $('#second-select').html(data);

                    },
                    error: function(data)  
                    {  
                    alert("Your browser broke create ayat  cpt select!");
                    return false;
                    }  


                }); //ajax

    return false;
}
```

Under functions.php:

```
function createAyatSelectCPT() {

$ca=$_GET['id']; 

?>
<form method="post" action="">  


            <select class="select2" id="selectid"> 

                            <?php

                            $my_query = new WP_Query();

                            $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                                            'terms' => array($ca) 
                                        )
                                    )
                                );


                            $my_query->query($args);


                            if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

                               ?>
                                        <option value="<?php the_ID();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                                <?php

                            endwhile;
                            endif;

            wp_reset_query();
            die();  
?>

</select>
</form>

<?php
}


add_action('wp_ajax_createAyatSelectCPT', 'createAyatSelectCPT');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_createAyatSelectCPT', 'createAyatSelectCPT');
```

The concerned HTML tag to modify is:

```
<div id="second-select">...</div>
```

**Edit 2 After installing Firebug :**

404 Not Found File: http://localehost.com/enc/products/stuff/stuff/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=createAyatSelectCPT&id=132

Then, the problem comes from the location `admin-ajax.php`. this file doesn't exist in this location. So the new permalink structure requires that I modify the path to admin-ajax.php in my jquery script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know what function is messing up the divs?

Is your jquery/ajax code changing the divs etc?  If so, can you provide us with the corresponding code snippet?

Also, does it happens when you use "/%postname%/%product_category%/" custom permalinks or any other custom ones as well.

Try using the Firebug plugin, and provide us with little more info so we can help you with this issue quickly and effectively.  Screenshots will also help.

Download Firebug:  http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: thank you for your quick feedack, I will follow your instructions and come back here provide with the required info. thanks again.

Comment: You are asking smart questions, I tried changing the structure to another one, and now I have another weird behaviour. +1 upvote. and then I will come back here to give an edit with all additional info you required. tnx

Comment: I have installed Firebug and it is a very useful tool. I edited my post with Firebug message.

Comment: Thank you, your advice is valuable

Comment: @whiteletters and blankspaces, were you able to figure out what was wrong using firebug?